# How to use ngIf without reloading page

Tags: angular

I have navbar component and my goal is to show two different navbars depending on user login, i.e. if user is logged in they will see one navbar; if not, another. I'm using ngIf for that purpose and everything works fine except that logged in user still see navbar for unlogged-in user until they refresh the page manually.

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '@models/user.model';
import {AuthenticationService} from '@services/auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  authObs: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private auth_service: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authObs =  this.auth_service.currentUser;
  }
```

```html
<nav *ngIf="authObs | async as auth; else elseBlock" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item sub">
          <a class="nav-link unselectable" (click)="gt_myprofile()"><span class="icon icon-profile"></span> my
            profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item sub">
          <a class="nav-link unselectable" (click)="gt_messages()"><span class="icon icon-message"></span> messages
            <span
              class="icon-notif"></span> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item sub">
          <a class="nav-link unselectable" (click)="gt_contacts()"><span class="icon icon-contacts"></span>
            contacts<span
              class="icon-notif"></span> </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/static" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!-- start navbar-nav -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">about<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">cooperation</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">terms</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">contacts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</ng-template>
```

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '@models/user.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }
}

login(email: string, password: string) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/auth/`, { email, password })
    .pipe(map(user => {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
      this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
      console.log("TCL: AuthenticationService -> login -> user", user)
      return user;
    }));
}
```

Comment: When do you ever update the `currentUserSubject`?

Comment: Sorry, how and when shoul I update it? After user logs in?

Comment: Well, if you want things that are consuming the observable to get the new value, that would be a good time to do that.

Comment: I added an answer, where I show how you can add a method to update the value for the loggedIn user.

Comment: try to clear local storage. Do you call removeItem from local storage on logout? I did not see logout function in your service. If local storage is empty, your code should work

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the `authService` not emitting the new value, otherwise the *ngIf and the async pipe usage looks good.

How do you invoke/use the authService to update the loggedIn information?

If you update the localStorage information to reflect whether the he user is loggedIn or not, you should emit the new value for the subject, something like:

```
updateUserAuth(newValue) {
    this.currentUserSubject.next(newValue);
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
}
```

You can invoke this method after the user login or whenever you want to update the currentUser state. This depends on your code logic, but it is important that you emit the new value, otherwise your subject will never notify that a new value is available to its subscribers.

---

Have you tried debugging the authObs variable and printout its value in the template?

```
   <.. *ngIf="authObs | async as auth; else elseBlock">
     Auth: {{auth}}
```

I think also you can skip the currentUser initialization in the constructor (or do you always keep user info stored locally until an explicit logout?):

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(...));

   // currentUser will be falsy for not logged in users. 
   // this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

Eventually could you create a stackBlitz example with your code?

Comment: I've forgotten to add login function from aurhService to my question, added it now. I already emit new value after user is loggenIn and it doesn't help.